# Deployed Tomcat 7 WAR application throws NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: web-applications, maven-2, classpath, noclassdeffounderror, tomcat7

I am working on a hello-world type of web application. I am using Eclipse Helios as my IDE, Maven 2 to handle dependencies, and a locally run Tomcat 7 server to deploy and test. The application is Spring MVC based and uses Hibernate for data management.

I can successfully package the project into a WAR file. When I deploy the WAR in Tomcat, the following error is reported in the logs:

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in
>   ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration
>     at
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) Etc...

I checked to be sure that the correct dependency is included in my POM, and it is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>
```

I checked to see that the packaged WAR file has the required JAR file which has the class mentioned (org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration) in the error and it does:

> ./Tomcat 7/webapps/helloworld/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar

Based on this information, I figure that this might be a classpath configuration issue. From the documentation I've read on Tomcat 7, Tomcat should be able to utilize the JAR files in "/WEB-INF/lib" folder. Any one know if I may have skipped a step in configuration of Tomcat in order for it to recognize the JAR files in the lib folder of a webapp?

Comment: The method I use to package up the webapp is: "mvn clean package". I also tried going to the "Server" view of Eclipse and added my Tomcat 7 server. I am able to bypass the NoClassDefFoundError by doing so. I would still like to know why Tomcat 7 won't utilize the JAR files in "Tomcat 7.0/webapps/<webapp-name>/WEB-INF/lib" when I package it using "mvn clean package".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this is generic advice, but I've had similar problems like this in the past with both Tomcat and Jetty and it was because I had multiple/wrong versions of some dependency.  I'd start by using the M2Eclipse POM editor in Eclipse and click on "Dependency Hierarchy" and carefully review all of the *transitive* dependencies.

Comment: I located a duplicate of one of my Maven dependencies with different versions (javax.server, servlet-api). When I removed the older dependency, Tomcat started up without my previously mentioned error. Thanks for the help, HDave!

Comment: You are welcome...sure wish Eclipse/Maven would automatically warn of such things.  Feel free to tick the upvote on the answer too!